# How to use different images for different screen sizes android?

Tags: android, imageview, android-resources

I have put my pictures with different sizes in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi e.t.c. But My ImageButtons that are using the image appear to be the same size on each device.

Last time I did this it worked by placing only the images in the folders. I don't remember exactly what I did though.

I want to display different size of images on different screens. 
I have

- 5.7 inch phone
- 5.0 inch phone
- 7.0 inch tablet

My app displays same size of image buttons in all of them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bg"
tools:context="test.music.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nowplayingname_txtv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:text="Ek Mulaqat-www.songsfarm.ifo"
            android:textColor="@color/title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/npduration_txtv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="05:12"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings_imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/bg"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="20dip"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/menu" />

</LinearLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/songs_listv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/song_seekbar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/prev_imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/bg"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/prev" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pp_imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/bg"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/play" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_imgbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/bg"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/next" />


</LinearLayout>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/song_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:paddingBottom="16dip"
    android:paddingTop="16dip" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3">


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#D3D3D3" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/song_seekbar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#D3D3D3" />

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note:** 
It's been a long time but it turns out placing the files in the correct folder works. The names of the files should be exactly the same. You can verify the size of images by comparing them to the images already present in folders.

Comment: What effect are you trying to get?  The same physical size in inches?  The same percentage of the screen used?  Something else?

Comment: I want to display different size of images on different screens. I have a 5.7 inches phone, a 5.0 inches phone and a 7  inch tablet. My app displays same size of image buttons in all of them

Comment: Different sizes-  different physical sizes, or logical sizes?  For example, do you want them all to be 1 inch tall, regardless of phone?  Or do you want them to all take up half the height?  Its unlikely you just want random different sizes.  You need to describe what your end result you want is in a more detailed manner, the answer is different depending on what that is.

Comment: To be correct, it's not different sized images you put in those folders, but rather higher resolution, which often are larger only to display more pixels

Comment: For example if I have a 1 inch screen and it show me picture size 0.2 inches. Than when screen size changes to 10 inches it should display an image of 2 inches.

Comment: Also, your ImageView probably has an explicitly set size, or is relative to the screen size itself. Therefore, all images regardless of size, will only fit into the ImageView depending on the attributes set

Comment: I am using relative layout but images are placed in linear layouts. and their sizes are wrap content.

Comment: THen dpi based ones probably aren't what you want.  I'd look into using swXXXX based resources, which allow you to specify different images for different screen sizes

Comment: "I'd look into using swXXXX based resources," what did  you mean here?? I dont understand

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [dimenify](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9349-dimenify) plugin. It will create standart set of dimens folders for different screens, and convert dimens values, for these screens. In that way your button will have it's own size for each screen:)

Comment: how can I add this plugin to android studio??

Comment: @PapManTwister just download .jar file and write path to it in File --> Settings --> Plugin from disk. After restarting your IDE click the right button of your mouse and choose "Create alternative resource folders"

Notice, that my solution will create alternative dimens folders and values, it means, that all your height, width and other params must be extracted in standart dimen folder.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to address is the confusion of what you mean by "screen size". Do you mean physical size (e.g. 4 inches wide vs 7 inches wide) or do you mean logical size (e.g. 360dp wide vs 600dp wide)?

In my experience, a lot of developers are concerned about physical size, not realizing that they should not be. The logical size of the display is a much bigger factor in how your app will appear to a user.

If you want to use different images for different physical sizes, there is no easy way to do this using the resources framework. You will have to compute the physical size of the screen yourself in Java using a `DisplayMetrics` object's `widthPixels` and `xdpi` fields, and then write code that uses e.g. `R.drawable.my_drawable_four_inches` or `R.drawable.my_drawable_seven_inches`.

If you want to use different images for different logical sizes, the resources framework will help you. You can set your drawable resources up like this:

```
res/
    drawable/
        my_drawable.png
    drawable-sw600dp/
        my_drawable.png
```

Now in your layouts and your Java code you can simply refer to `@drawable/my_drawable` or `R.drawable.my_drawable`, and the system will automatically pick the right one for you. Any device 600dp or wider will get the second file, and any device 559dp or narrower will get the first.

On top of all this, you might want to consider providing multiple copies of the same image for different screen resolutions. That's a little outside the scope of this answer, but you can read about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence